# Location Settings for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

How do I show a link to Location Settings using window phone API. I am able to show link to enable Wifi, but cannot find anywhere how to show Location Setting

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.. Because location settings are specific to each and every application. That is how the implementation is expected to be by MS as well. Otherwise your app would be rejected. So, your application should have a settings option where the user can disable and enable the location access for your application. But while accessing the location you must also consider the Phone Location access settings too.

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher g = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            g.Start();
            if (g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Granted))
            {
                // Check application level access and proceed
            }
            else if (g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Denied) || g.Permission.Equals(GeoPositionPermission.Unknown))
            {
                // Your code/message to the user notifying about location access being disabled at the device level
            }
```